# How to include a python module in our project directory?

Tags: python, python-module

I would like to add the pygame and PIL modules as files in my project. My goal is to not have to install them by typing `pip install` in the console prompt. So I'm looking for a way to physically add them in the project directory. Thank you.

Comment: you can download their package .zip file (or .tar) and simply put them into your project directory, but this is not recommended as PIL is a large python package.

Answer (score 0):

I'm quite sure you don't really want to do this, since both the modules you listed have binary components specific to Python and OS version/architecture. You'd have to ship all of them, for all versions you expect to run your project on.

Just add instructions on how to install them, instead.